# Multiple Gaussian curves in different locations in one Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to have multiple Gaussian curves in different locations in one Tikz figure.

I am unable to place each Gaussian curve on top of its intended point (2, 6 and 12 in the following code). <strike>Also, two curves don't even look Gaussian.</strike>

<strike>I also wanted to get rid of the straight lines between the curves, so I made three different axes, and had compile errors.</strike>

EDIT: Based on the comment by Torbjørn, I modified the code. I still remain with the issue of non-matching coordinates between the axis and the figure.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma

\newcommand\tX{0}
\newcommand\tY{0}

% Define Nodes
\node[](t1) at ({\tX+0},{\tY}){};
\node[](t2) at ({\tX+2},{\tY}){};
\node[](t3) at ({\tX+6},{\tY}){};
\node[](t4) at ({\tX+12},{\tY}){};
\node[](t5) at ({\tX+14},{\tY}){};

% Draw line between them
\draw[line width=1pt] let \p1=(t1), \p2=(t2), \p3=(t3), \p4=(t4), \p5=(t5) in
     (\p1)--(\p2)--(\p3)--(\p4)--(\p5) ;

\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {
    \node[](tmp) at (t\x) {};
    \draw[line width=1pt] let \p1=(tmp) in (\x1,{\y1-3})--(\x1,{\y1+3});
}

\begin{axis}[
  hide axis,
  no markers,
  at={(0,0)},
  y=0.5cm,
  x=1cm] 
\addplot[samples=50, domain=1:3] {\gauss{2}{0.1}};
\addplot[samples=50, domain=4.5:7.5] {\gauss{6}{0.3}};
\addplot[samples=50, domain=11:13] {\gauss{12}{0.1}};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `smooth`, that causes the artifacts you see. Use more samples, and set different domains for each `\addplot`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified the code accordingly. I still have non-matching coordinates for the axis and the figure. The gaussian curves are shifted a bit to the right from their intended mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mixing normal `tikz` commands and PGFPlots `axis` environments can be a bit tricky sometimes. In this case, I think it's best to just stick with PGFPlots: you can tweak the axis appearance to give you the desired result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma

\begin{axis}[
  hide y axis,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  xtick align=center,
  tickwidth=0.3cm,
  xticklabels={},
  xmin=0, xmax=14,
  xtick={0,2, 6, 12, 14},
  no markers,
  at={(0,0)},
  y=0.5cm,
  x=1cm] 
\addplot[samples=50, domain=1:3] {\gauss{2}{0.1}};
\addplot[samples=50, domain=4.5:7.5] {\gauss{6}{0.3}};
\addplot[samples=50, domain=11:13] {\gauss{12}{0.1}};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and thanks for including the xticklabels. My plot is complete now.